# How to import a dll in an exe file without including the header file in visualC++ 2008?

Tags: visual-c++-2008

I am in the starting stage of programming.

I have created a `.dll` file. I want to link it in an `.exe` file. I have used the `__declspec(dllimport)` function, but it shows some error. How can I link the `.dll` to the `.exe.`

Please help me...

Thanks in Advance...

Comment: What is the error shown?

Comment: Error 2 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) double __cdecl bonus(double,double)" (__imp_?bonus@@YANNN@Z) referenced in function _main main.obj main
 this is the error